# Scala Spark handle files with special characters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filenames

I have a file such as C:/aaa a+b[1234].res.1.txt and I try to process it using SparkContext, e.g.:

```
...
sc.textFile(filename).cache()
val count = cache.filter(line => line.contains("e")).count()
...
```

Unfortunately this raises an exception:

```
Input Pattern file:/C:/aaa a+b[1234].abc.1.txt matches 0 files
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input Pattern file:/C:/aaa a+b[1234].res.1.txt matches 0 files
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:251)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
```

Probably this is error is due to the brackets "[" and  "]" in the filename. If I simplify the filename I receive results. How can I encode the filename to succeed the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after Kirans suggestion I came up with a possible solution:

```
sc.textFile(filename.replace("[","?").replace("]","?"))
```

The '?' basically represents any character. Although that might be working in my use case I wonder if there isnt anything better since obviously it might happen that I read two files where I only want to read one

Comment: the solution worked for spark itself. However if u use another library which builds on spark such as sparkcsv the problem occurs again (even with the wildcard...seems that internally the wildcard gets resolved). To get around it I create a link in the filesystem for each file that I want to analyse.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow we can't escape these:
1) ":" Can u use relative path from your FS root? I didnt work on Windows.

2) "[" & "]" I think because they are used in regular expressions.

I have a work-around for "[", "]": 
sc.textFile(filename.replace("[","*").replace("[","*")).collect()

Comment: well if I do that `.replace("[","").replace("[","")` I get an Input path exception does not exist. Of course I could rename the file first, however this seems to be an rather complicated solution

Comment: and regarding 1) I can use relative path as well as absolut ones, in both cases it works if I have a file name without the brackets.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say to use a wildcard character("*" or "?"). Somehow that character is stripped off in my reply.